# Why doesn't Darth Vader's breath rate increase while he is fighting?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Is it because he is a Jedi? Or does it and it is simply inaudible?

Comment: Do you have some evidence of the fact that it does not increase?

Comment: I'm assuming you're mostly referring to episodes 4-6 where his breathing is regulated by artificial means. There are a few scenes where his breathing does not match up with his dialog, so I don't know that his breathing rate is ever really accurate in those movies.

Answer (score 6):

It's because he's not actually breathing himself.  His breathing is controlled by his suit, which is a mobile iron lung.  See the question "[Why was the cyborg Darth Vader wheezy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/why-was-the-cyborg-darth-vader-wheezy)" for more info.

Comment: Makes sense - this would also mean his V02 max could never increase.  Perhaps his heart rate is always constant, or if not, his suit would monitor when more blood is required in the blood vessels he has left, as well as managing his breathing and oxygen flow for him.

Answer (score 4):

Given he has no arms and legs I don't think he would require similar levels of oxygen. Also, I would assume anyone who has mastered the force to the level of Vader will actually expend very little energy during a battle and therefore would have a constant metabolism.

Comment: Interesting, although other Jedi knights have displayed shortness of breath / tiredness during physical combat. Perhaps these knights were not as powerful as Vader and had not yet mastered complete control of their own mind / bodies, which encompasses metabolism.

Comment: I don't think Vader ever ran, which might explain it.

Comment: Maybe he cant run. Wonder what is 100m time is.